# Unexpected strlen result for a string literal

Tags: c++, string, strlen

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{   
    auto l = std::strlen("123\0456\0");
    std::cout << l << std::endl;
}
```

Why is the output of this code 5?

I expected 3.

Here is an online version to test:
https://ideone.com/UQRKlV

Comment: there exitst code that one needs to treat with caution, however nothing will break if you try to compile this code. Why you cannot answer the question yourself?

Comment: Here is a live version: [https://ideone.com/UQRKlV](https://ideone.com/UQRKlV)

Comment: `What will be the output of that code` did you compile and check what the output is?  `also please explain why?` Do you have tried to figure out what might cause that not everything is shown?

Comment: Why _does_ this output 5? When I hover over the string literal in VS 2019, it tells me it's a `const char[7] "123%6\000"`. Why is `\045` being treated as `%`, why does it group the characters `\045` together (as opposed to `\0`, `\04`, or some other chunking), and why does it terminate with `\000` instead of `\0`?

Comment: None of the answers so far has mentioned this, but you can build the string literal that you expected with `auto l = std::strlen("123\0" "456\0");`.

Comment: Or you could use `"123\000456\0"` without concatenating.

Answer (score 8):

`"123\0456\0"` is a *literal* of type `const char[7]`.

`\045` is a single character, specified in octal. In ASCII it's `'%'`. Here `\0` is **not** denoting `NUL` since the *maximal munch* parsing rules extract `\045` as an *octal escape sequence*: note that 0, 4, and 5 are valid octal digits and that an octal escape sequence cannot be longer than 3 digits.

The second `\0` is an explicit `NUL`, and there's an implied extra `NUL` at the end of the literal.

`strlen` will return 5 since there are that many characters before the first `NUL`.

Comment: And just to be explicit, the first `\0` is NOT a null character, because it's followed by two more octal-valid digits. So those digits are part of the escape sequence.

Comment: @FredLarson: Exactly! Worth adding that in.

Comment: So is `\0456` not a valid escape sequence? If I just write `char c = 0456; std::cout << c;` it prints a `.` to the terminal. Is that invoking UB because `302` isn't a valid ASCII value?

Comment: @NathanPierson: Octal escape sequences have a max of three digits.

Comment: @NathanPierson `0456` is not escaped in any way (there is no leading ```\```), it is just a plain ordinary [integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) in octal form. The compiler will implicitly convert the `int` value (octal 456, decimal 302) as-is to the `char`, but the max value a `char` can hold is decimal 127 (octal 177), so the `char` will overflow, which in your case *happens* to produce a `char` value of decimal 46 (octal 56), which is the ASCII character `.`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Actually, it doesn't ignore the leading `0`, it treats it as an octal integer literal with decimal value `302`. But that explains what's going on with the conversion to `char`, thank you.

Comment: @NathanPierson thanks, I forgot that integer literals also support octal, I have fixed my comment.

Answer (score 4):

Characters in a literal can be [*escaped*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) using either hex (`\xNN`), octal (`\0NN`), or Unicode (`\uNNNN`, `\UNNNNNNNN`) notation.

In your string literal, `"123\0456\0"`, `\045` and `\0` are OCTAL escape sequences.

You are expecting the compiler to parse the 1st `\0` as a 1-digit octal sequence for a NUL terminator, but it is actually parsed as a 3-digit octal sequence instead, because octal uses up to 3 digits max, and 0, 4, and 5 are valid octal digits.  So the compiler will parse the 3-digit `\045` sequence as a single `char` having a numeric value of octal 45 (decimal 37, hex 0x25), which in *most* (not all) charsets is the ASCII `%` character, and it will parse the 2nd 1-digit `\0` sequence as a single `char` having a numeric value of octal 0 (decimal 0, hex 0x00), which in all charsets is a `NUL` character.

So, `"123\0456\0"` has 7 `char`s total (including the implicit null terminator at the end):

`1 2 3 % 6 NUL NUL`

`strlen()` will count `char`s until it encounters a `NUL` character.  Which is why the output is 5, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

First read about [string literals in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). Look for special meaning of [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Then read what [strlen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) does and combine this knowledge to explain outcome.

Comment: Relevant quote re. escape sequences: "Octal escape sequences have a limit of three octal digits, but terminate at the first character that is not a valid octal digit if encountered sooner."